# How to fix compiler issue "method does not override a method from its superclass @Override" for run method in Runnable?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, runnable

I am trying to create a basic Thread with a Runnable object in Java. Below is my code:

```
import java.lang.Thread;
import java.lang.Runnable;

public class TestRunnable{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyRunnableImplementation r = new MyRunnableImplementation();
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();
    }
}

public class MyRunnableImplementation implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Testing");
    }
}
```

However the compiler raises an issue:
method does not override a method from its superclass @Override

How can I fix this?

EDIT:

I have also tried the below code which returns the same issue:

```
public class TestRunnable implements Runnable{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Runnable runnable = new TestRunnable();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Testing");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have another class in the same package called `Runnable`?

Comment: [Looks fine to me](https://ideone.com/06yJpk). There's something you're not showing us.

Comment: remove `@Override` annotation and try

Comment: @BhanuDevapatla The annotation is doing exactly what it's supposed to in this situation - alerting you that there's a problem. Removing the annotation does not solve the problem.

Comment: Andy, No other classes called Runnable. Michael, that's all the code.

Comment: Is there a reason for you to explicitly import `java.lang.Runnable` and `java.lang.Thread`?

Comment: I guess it is something to do with java version that you are using. Are you using java 5 by any chance?

Comment: I just tried your code and it works. How you compile this code?

Comment: I am using Java Version 8. I am compiling this program on the windows cmd line using "javac".

Comment: I compiled with javac - it works. I need your package names of java classes and please also show full javac command you run. You can edit your question to provide info.

Comment: Pavlo - this java file is stored in a Windows folder with no other files present. I am not using an IDE.

The command I run is:
javac TestRunnable.java

Answer (score 1):

No two public classes may reside in the same java source; hence the answer of @boobalan_gnanasekaran.

Also Runnable is an *interface*. In really old versions of java `@Override` was allowed for *class* methods only. So ensure that the java version is fine. I suggest trying out some more modern constructs:

```
Optional<String> opt = Optional.empty();
```

If that does not compile, update the java version.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my opinion. It happens a lot in my projects where I use gradle for build tool. By default it uses java 1.5 as the version.

Comment: Are you saying that you shouldn't use the @Override annotation when implementing methods from an interface?

Comment: @Rjon if you happen to use old version of java then you should not. `@Override` for interface methods is only supported from 1.6

Comment: @Rjon, no just that then one is using 1.5 instead of 8. Of course 8 or 9 should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `public` keyword from the line, `public class MyRunnableImplementation implements Runnable {..`; that may clean up the code

Comment: Still getting the same issue after removing "public"

Comment: I guess this doesn't answer the question, however I still upvote because you cannot have two public classes in the same file (this took me by surprise when I moved to java from c#)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question but it is a useful side note.